# How to translate the text in the flutter app into sign language?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make an app that can change it`s language to sign language but I couldn`t find any resources or packages that can help me change text to sign language

Answer (score 0):

What do You mean when You write about "sign language"?
You can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/localization and detect system language or manually choose language. How to set manually language? For example You can create dropdown with list of supported languages and switch langue every time, when You change app language on dropdown button.